# Как сделать выделение строки?

Tags: java, jtable

Есть таблица JTable, на нее вешаю такой рендер:

```
public class TableCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer{
@Override
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
            boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    String text;
    if(value.getClass() == Integer.class) text = Integer.toString((int)value);
    else if(value.getClass() == Double.class) text = Double.toString((double)value);
    else if(value.getClass() == String.class) text = "  "+(String) value;
    else text = Long.toString((long)value);
    if(column == 2) text += "\u0584"; // стоимость
    if(column == 3) text += "ч.";     // время
    if(column == 6){                  // дата
        if((long)value == -1) text = "";
        else{
            Date d = new Date();
            d.setTime((long)value);
            text = org.AppLoader.DATE_FRMT.format(d) + "г.";
        }
    }
    if(column == 7) text += "%";      // процент
    if(text.contains("-1")) text ="";

    JLabel lbl = new JLabel(text);
    // установка шрифтов
    if(column == 0)lbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 12)); // шрифт первой колонки
    else if(column != 1) lbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 16));
    else lbl.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 1, 16)); // шрифт второй колонки

    if(column != 1)lbl.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    // настройка цветов оцкнуи и УЦ
    if(column == 5){
        if((int)value > 8) lbl.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 255));
        else if((int)value > 6) lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        else if((int)value > 4) lbl.setForeground(new Color(240,240,0));
        else if((int)value > 2) lbl.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        else lbl.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
    if(column == 4){
        if((double)value == 0) lbl.setForeground(new Color(0, 255, 255));
        else if((double)value <= 10) lbl.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
        else if((double)value <= 30) lbl.setForeground(Color.ORANGE);
        else lbl.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
    lbl.setFocusable(true);
return lbl;
}
```

}

Предполагаю, что из-за того, что я возвращаю JLabel, убирается возможность редактирования и выделения ячеек. На что можно заменить JLabel, чтобы осталось форматирование, но была возможность выделить ячейку?

Answer (score 0):

Нашел для JLabel методом тыка

```
if (isSelected==true) lbl.setForeground(new Color(200,200,200));
```

Так выделенная ячейка меняет фон